# Logging the results of this function

Tags: javascript

Somebody please explain me this code in detail

```
function reverse(s){
   return s.split("").reverse().join("");
}
```

Comment: What part of it don't you understand?

Comment: It assumes the input to be a string. Given the input, the string is [split](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/split) using an empty string as delimiter. The result is an array, consisting of individual characters. Then, the [`reverse`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reverse) method of Array is used to reverse the order of the array's elements. Then, the string is concatenated again, using an empty string.

Comment: Sorry all, I misunderstood the function. I thought reverse() is being called from the same function.. Thanks for answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function takes a string, it splits it in its constituent characters to obtain an array using the [`split`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String) function, it reverses this array using the [`reverse`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reverse) method and [`join`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join)s the elements with an empty string.

Basically it reverses a string which given the name of the function I guess doesn't come as a surprise to anyone.

So:

```
reverse('abc')
```

will return:

```
cba
```